# WIA 2.0, where can i found valid values for the properties? C#

Tags: c#, image, properties, wia, image-scanner

i was serching for valid values for the properties **"Document handling select"** and **"Pages"** for a scanner, im using WIA reference of Microsoft.
Some values that i found (0,1,4 for Document handlig property) (0 for pages property) does not work.
Can you tell me where can i found full documentation of WIA?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, this will get all the properties of the device and item and check if there a range and possible values where you can set. Even though i am struggling on how to set the device property to work with feeder only and scan duplex.

```
 foreach (WIA.Property prop in WiaDev.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " - " + prop.PropertyID + " :  " + prop.get_Value() + "  No range");
                    if (prop.SubType == WiaSubType.ListSubType || prop.SubType == WiaSubType.FlagSubType)
                    {
                        Vector v = prop.SubTypeValues;
                        var enumerator = v.GetEnumerator();
                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            Console.WriteLine("Possible Values: " + enumerator.Current);

                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------");
                foreach (WIA.Property prop in Item.Properties)
                {
                    if (prop.SubType == WiaSubType.RangeSubType)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " - " + prop.PropertyID + " :  " + prop.get_Value() + "  Min: " + prop.SubTypeMin + " Max: " + prop.SubTypeMax);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " - " + prop.PropertyID + " :  " + prop.get_Value() + "  No range");
                    }

                    if (prop.SubType == WiaSubType.ListSubType || prop.SubType == WiaSubType.FlagSubType)
                    {
                        Vector v = prop.SubTypeValues;
                        var enumerator = v.GetEnumerator();
                        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                            Console.WriteLine("Possible Values: " + enumerator.Current);

                    }
                }
```